SqsListener not working in Sprint Boot 3.3.0
I am trying to upgrade one of my services to Spring Boot 3.x from Spring Boot 2.7.x
Current Versions:
Spring Boot: 3.3.0
Java: 21
Spring AWS Cloud: 3.1.1
Unfortunately, @SqsListener is not working and I am not receiving any message from any of the queues.
build.gradle file looks like this
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.3.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.5'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "2023.0.1")
    set('springCloudAwsVersion','3.1.1')
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-starter'
    implementation 'io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-starter-sqs'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
        mavenBom "io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-dependencies:${springCloudAwsVersion}"
    }
}

Java Code:
@SqsListener(value = "${sqs.queue}", acknowledgementMode = ON_SUCCESS)
public void consumeMessage(String payload) {
    doSomething(payload);
}

I also tried creating the beans of SqsAsyncClient and SqsMessageListenerContainerFactory though they are not required but still I am not able to receive the payload.
@Bean
public SqsAsyncClient sqsAsyncClient() {
    return SqsAsyncClient.builder().region(Region.AP_SOUTH_1).build();
}

@Bean
public SqsMessageListenerContainerFactory<Object> defaultSqsListenerContainerFactory() {
  return SqsMessageListenerContainerFactory
                .builder()
                .sqsAsyncClient(sqsAsyncClient())
                .build();
}

I also tried downgrading Spring Boot to 3.2.5 but still the same issue.
Is there anything I am missing here?
Thanks in advance.
